# OpenGL redraw scene when receive an input

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl

I have implement a thread in a visual C++ app that draw in a OpenGL window a series of cubes related to a vector of cubes, of what I have center, side and level. It's a vector of this class object, like a tree, with various levels and stratification. During main elaboration, the cubes in this object change: added, removed...at every step of elaboration...

I need to redraw (refresh) the content of OpenGL window only when the every step it's completed, to obtain a dynamic representation of evolve of that list of cubes.

I mean:

- First step done, I pass array to OpenGL thread, that draw.
- Second step run, content of OpenGL window mantain first cube.
- Secondo step done, content of OpenGL was updated with new cubes.
- And so on...

The OpenGL thread it's in a background mode thread...I need only to see the evolution of cubes only when I do elaboration...now, the problem it's that with the statement glutMainLoop() the situation it's continuos...and it's too heavy or crash, even with a system with a Nvidia Quadro 4000....OpenGL windows showed, but blocked, unmovable and sometimes grey or don't show anything.

Here is piece of my code (all that related to OpenGL):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <queue>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


 //Premessa delle funzioni di posizionamento con mouse 
  void mouseCB(int button, int stat, int x, int y);
  void mouseMotionCB(int x, int y);

  //funzioni di inizializzazione e pulizia
  bool initSharedMem();
 void clearSharedMem();
 void initLights();
 void setCamera(float posX, float posY, float posZ, float targetX, float targetY, float    targetZ);
  void toOrtho();
 void toPerspective();

 //variabili e costanti
 const int   SCREEN_WIDTH    = 640;
 const int   SCREEN_HEIGHT   = 480;
const float CAMERA_DISTANCE = 10.0f;

int screenWidth;
int screenHeight;
bool mouseLeftDown;
 bool mouseRightDown;
 bool mouseMiddleDown;
 float mouseX, mouseY;
float cameraAngleX;
 float cameraAngleY;
float cameraDistance;
int drawMode;

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Funzione inizializzazione OpenGL standard
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void init()
{
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,GL_NICEST);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING); 
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
initLights();
 }

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Funzione di inizializzazione globale delle variabili
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
bool initSharedMem()
{
screenWidth = SCREEN_WIDTH;
screenHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT;

mouseLeftDown = mouseRightDown = mouseMiddleDown = false;
mouseX = mouseY = 0;

cameraAngleX = cameraAngleY = 0.0f;
//cameraDistance = CAMERA_DISTANCE;
cameraDistance = 0.3f;
drawMode = 0; // 0:pieno, 1: solo contorni, 2:punti

return true;
}

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Funzione di pulitura variabili globali
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void clearSharedMem()
{
 }

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Inizializzazione Luci
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void initLights()
{
GLfloat lightKa[] = {.2f, .2f, .2f, 1.0f};  // luce ambientale
GLfloat lightKd[] = {.7f, .7f, .7f, 1.0f};  // luce diffusa
GLfloat lightKs[] = {1, 1, 1, 1};           // luce speculare

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, lightKa);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightKd);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, lightKs);

// posizione delle luci
float lightPos[4] = {0, 0, 20, 1}; 
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos);

//Attiva tutti i settaggi delle luci
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);                        }

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //  Posizione della telecamera e direzioni
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 void setCamera(float posX, float posY, float posZ, float targetX, float targetY, float   targetZ)
{
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(posX, posY, posZ, targetX, targetY, targetZ, 0, 1, 0); // eye(x,y,z),  focal(x,y,z), up(x,y,z)
 }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Impostazione proiezione ortogonale
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 void toOrtho()
{
// Imposta il viewport di tutta la finestra
glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)screenWidth, (GLsizei)screenHeight);

// Imposta il frustum di visione
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, screenWidth, 0, screenHeight, -1, 1);

// passaggio a modelview per interattività
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
}



 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Impostazione come perspective
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void toPerspective()
{ 
// Imposta il viewport di tutta la finestra
glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)screenWidth, (GLsizei)screenHeight);

//frustum perspective
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

//gluPerspective(60.0f, (float)(screenWidth)/screenHeight, 1.0f, 1000.0f);

gluPerspective(60.0f, (float)(screenWidth)/screenHeight, 10.0f, 0.0f); // FOV,   AspectRatio, NearClip, FarClip

// switch to modelview matrix in order to set scene
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
}

   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //  Funzione ricorsiva di disegno
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  void addraw(cubo temp)
 {
//se non ci sono sottocubi
   if (temp.lista_sottocubi.size() == 0)
   {        
        if (temp.livello == LMAXI) {
             double centro[3]={(temp.V[6].x)/2, (temp.V[6].y)/2,         (temp.V[6].z)/2};
             glPushMatrix();
             glTranslatef(centro[0],centro[1],centro[2]);
             glColor3ub(0,0,255);
             glutSolidCube(temp.lato);
             glPopMatrix();
        }
}
//se i sottocubi ci sono
else {
    for (int i=0;i<(int)temp.lista_sottocubi.size();i++){
            addraw(temp.lista_sottocubi[i]);
        }
 }
}

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Funzione disegno principale
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 void draw()
{

// clear buffer
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
glPushMatrix();

//spostamento del disegno
glTranslatef(0, 0, -cameraDistance);
glRotatef(cameraAngleX, 1, 0, 0);   // pitch
glRotatef(cameraAngleY, 0, 1, 0);   // heading

//lancio funzione di disegno vera e propria
addraw(prova);

//reset
glPopMatrix();
glutSwapBuffers();
 }
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //  Funzione di reshape
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
 screenWidth = w;
  screenHeight = h;
 toPerspective();
 }

   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Funzione di refresh temporizzato della finestra
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    void timerCB(int millisec){
glutTimerFunc(millisec, timerCB, millisec);
glutPostRedisplay();
  }

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Funzione rilevamento movimenti del mouse
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Motion(int x,int y)
{
if(mouseLeftDown)
{
    cameraAngleY += (x - mouseX);
    cameraAngleX += (y - mouseY);
    mouseX = x;
    mouseY = y;
}
if(mouseRightDown)
{
    cameraDistance -= (y - mouseY) * 0.2f;
    mouseY = y;
    }
 }

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Funzione per rilevamento bottoni mouse
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
mouseX = x;
mouseY = y;

if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON)
{
    if(state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        mouseLeftDown = true;
    }
    else if(state == GLUT_UP)
        mouseLeftDown = false;
}

 else if(button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON)
 {
    if(state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        mouseRightDown = true;
    }
    else if(state == GLUT_UP)
        mouseRightDown = false;
 }

 else if(button == GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON)
 {
    if(state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        mouseMiddleDown = true;
    }
    else if(state == GLUT_UP)
        mouseMiddleDown = false;
   }
  }

   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Inizializzazione di GLUT
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  void initGLUT(){
 //parametri fake per il lancio di InitGlut
char *myargv[1];
int myargc = 1;
myargv[0]=strdup("MyOpenGL");

//Inizializzazione Glut basso livello
glutInit(&myargc,myargv);

//Lancio funzioni di settaggio finestra,visualizzazione ed altro
glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA| GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH |GLUT_STENCIL);    
glutInitWindowSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
glutInitWindowPosition(850,100);
glutCreateWindow("Ricostruzione attuale");

    //callback delle funzioni richiamate
    glutDisplayFunc(draw);
    glutTimerFunc(33,timerCB,33);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMouseFunc(Mouse);
    glutMotionFunc(Motion);

}

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //  Thread richiamato per lanciare OPENGL
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void DRAW3D (void *param){

//abbassa priorità del thread a backgroud
if(!SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN))
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        if (ERROR_THREAD_MODE_ALREADY_BACKGROUND == dwError)
        _tprintf(TEXT("Gia' in background\n"));
        else _tprintf(TEXT("Errore nell'entrare in modalita' background (%d)\n"), dwError);
    }

    // Lancia funzione di inizializzazione variabili globali
    initSharedMem();

    //initiGLUT
    initGLUT();
    init();

    //ciclo OpenGL
    glutMainLoop();

    _endthread();
```

}

where prova it's a vector container of cubes object instanced from a class that defines cube by 6 vertex and a size of side (lato) and level.

Removing the recursive function "addraw" with a simple first level "read and draw" function (without recursivity) resolve the problem (windows show correct 1° level cubes, rotable, zoomable...no crash or blocked window) but I need to draw all cubes of maximum level in every ramification...so I need that recursive scan of vector...

So, I don't know how do this...someone can help me?

1) How can I refresh OpenGL draw only when I need?
2) How draw with OpenGL thread a series of cube contained in a multilevel vector?

I'm on Visual C++ 2010 under Windows 7 64 bit, freeglut 2.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute easiest thing to do is to create a display callback and use something like `glutPostRedisplay (...)` as a means of signaling your thread's main loop to invoke your display callback. In GLUT, that function basically increments a counter that is reset at the end of every iteration of the main loop and tells GLUT that the window is dirty (needs to be redrawn) if it has a value > 0.

Semaphores would be overkill here, they are useful when you need to prevent simultaneous access to a resource. That is not at all what you need. The most complicated approach to this problem would be to put your drawing thread to sleep until it receives a signal to redraw. This is an acceptable approach for non-interactive rendering, but for interactive rendering a simple busy-wait loop that checks the "dirty" flag described above would get the job done (in fact, I *believe* this is how some implementations of GLUT's main loop work).

The reason I suggest avoiding GLUT here is that some implementations (e.g. the version that ships with OS X) have known issues with running its main loop in a secondary thread.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I've updated my question with my code. Is that glutPostRedisplay that you mean? This is the actual code, and this is heavy, rotation, zoom it's slow and on that PC it's freeze and OpenGL window it's like blocked. Please tell me where I have to modify that code to obtain what I need..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using semaphores in your code? [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is more information about it.

Comment: Sounds more like a use case for a condition variable/signal